# How to connect listbox to table c# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a table and a form with a `listBox1`.
I want values from one column from the table will be displayed in the `listBox1`.
For example:

the table columns: Id , Name , Phone

the table rows:

```
        1 , abc , 123 

        2 , atg , 124

        24 , awt, 155
```

in the listBox1:

```
         1

         2

         24
```

and I also need to know on which one did I clicked from the listBox1.
For example: I clicked on the '24' in the `listBox1` and the value '24' will show in `textBox1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set these properties?

```
listBox1.DataSource = yourTable;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
```

In this way, your listbox will show the column name, but when you click an item you could get the value (ID) associated with that name

```
    private void ListBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            int personID = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
            .......
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is an example. You need to connect this method to the event SelectedValueChanged. Search in your property designer window under the bolt icon or add somewhere in your code `listBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedValueChanged);`